# Use ReadAsAsync<T> to map data complex JSON data

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to map some data from a JSON response with a complex structure.

I want to keep it simple to only capture the data that I need.
Don't want to use some auto generator to generate a big class with the properties that I am not going to use.
So I have created a simple class:

```
public class CurrencyRateModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

Was thinking to use the following to map the necessary data:

```
CurrencyRateModel currencyRate = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CurrencyRateModel>()
```

But by looking at the JSON response, I am pretty sure that it won't be able to map the data correctly.

```
{"header":{"id":"IREF188519","prepared":"2020-07-08T14:34:16","test":false,"sender":{"id":"NB"},"receiver":{"id":"ANONYMOUS"}},"dataSets":[{"action":"Information","series":{"0:0:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["6.5808"]}},"0:1:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["546.5"]}},"0:2:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["1.7685"]}},"0:3:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["6.9686"]}},"0:4:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["1006.07"]}},"0:5:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["135.02"]}},"0:6:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["39.96"]}},"0:7:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["143.48"]}},"0:8:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["10.6885"]}},"0:9:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["11.8863"]}},"0:10:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["1.222"]}},"0:11:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["141.79"]}},"0:12:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["3.0067"]}},"0:13:0:0":{"attributes":[1,1,0,0],"observations":{"0":["114.62"]}},"0:14:0:0":{"attributes":[3,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["0.065703"]}},"0:15:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["2.7442"]}},"0:16:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["12.627"]}},"0:17:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["8.8051"]}},"0:18:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["0.7924"]}},"0:19:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["41.68"]}},"0:20:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["2.2167"]}},"0:21:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["6.2009"]}},"0:22:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["19.121"]}},"0:23:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["5.666"]}},"0:24:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["2.3877"]}},"0:25:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["220.8"]}},"0:26:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["13.285"]}},"0:27:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["102.47"]}},"0:28:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["6.7885"]}},"0:29:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["30.32"]}},"0:30:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["137.96"]}},"0:31:0:0":{"attributes":[2,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["32.153"]}},"0:32:0:0":{"attributes":[1,1,0,0],"observations":{"0":["125.89"]}},"0:33:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["9.4706"]}},"0:34:0:0":{"attributes":[4,1,0,0],"observations":{"0":["13.15676"]}},"0:35:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["0.5578"]}},"0:36:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["3.8759"]}},"0:37:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["11.17"]}},"0:38:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["0.6956"]}},"0:39:0:0":{"attributes":[1,0,1,0],"observations":{"0":["6.79"]}}}}],"structure":{"name":"Exchange rates","description":"exchange rate statistics","dimensions":{"dataset":[],"series":[{"id":"FREQ","name":"Frequency","description":"The time interval at which observations occur over a given time period.","keyPosition":0,"role":null,"values":[{"position":3,"id":"B","name":"Business"}]},{"id":"BASE_CUR","name":"Base Currency","description":"The first currency in a currency pair quotation. Also known as the transaction currency.","keyPosition":1,"role":null,"values":[{"position":8,"id":"AUD","name":"Australian dollar"},{"position":11,"id":"BGN","name":"Bulgarian lev"},{"position":9,"id":"BRL","name":"Brazilian real"},{"position":18,"id":"CAD","name":"Canadian dollar"},{"position":2,"id":"CHF","name":"Swiss franc"},{"position":19,"id":"CNY","name":"Chinese yuan"},{"position":22,"id":"CZK","name":"Czech koruna"},{"position":6,"id":"DKK","name":"Danish krone"},{"position":4,"id":"EUR","name":"Euro"},{"position":10,"id":"GBP","name":"Pound sterling"},{"position":13,"id":"HKD","name":"Hong Kong dollar"},{"position":20,"id":"HRK","name":"Croatian kuna"},{"position":23,"id":"HUF","name":"Hungarian forint"},{"position":5,"id":"I44","name":"Import-weighted krone exchange rate"},{"position":15,"id":"IDR","name":"Indonesian rupiah"},{"position":16,"id":"ILS","name":"Israeli new shekel"},{"position":24,"id":"INR","name":"Indian rupee"},{"position":17,"id":"JPY","name":"Japanese yen"},{"position":25,"id":"KRW","name":"South Korean won"},{"position":21,"id":"MXN","name":"Mexican peso"},{"position":27,"id":"MYR","name":"Malaysian ringgit"},{"position":28,"id":"NZD","name":"New Zealand dollar"},{"position":12,"id":"PHP","name":"Philippine peso"},{"position":29,"id":"PKR","name":"Pakistani rupee"},{"position":30,"id":"PLN","name":"Polish zloty"},{"position":31,"id":"RON","name":"New Romanian leu"},{"position":32,"id":"RUB","name":"Russian rouble"},{"position":33,"id":"SEK","name":"Swedish krona"},{"position":34,"id":"SGD","name":"Singapore dollar"},{"position":35,"id":"THB","name":"Thai baht"},{"position":36,"id":"TRY","name":"Turkish lira"},{"position":37,"id":"TWD","name":"New Taiwan dollar"},{"position":38,"id":"TWI","name":"Trade-weighted krone exchange rate"},{"position":3,"id":"USD","name":"US dollar"},{"position":14,"id":"XDR","name":"IMF, special drawing rights"},{"position":39,"id":"ZAR","name":"South African rand"},{"position":40,"id":"BYN","name":"Belarusian new rouble"},{"position":42,"id":"BDT","name":"Bangladeshi taka"},{"position":43,"id":"MMK","name":"Myanmar kyat"},{"position":7,"id":"ISK","name":"Icelandic krona"}]},{"id":"QUOTE_CUR","name":"Quote Currency","description":"The second currency in a currency quote pair. Also known as counter currency.","keyPosition":2,"role":null,"values":[{"position":1,"id":"NOK","name":"Norwegian krone"}]},{"id":"TENOR","name":"Tenor","description":"The amount of time left for the repayment of a loan or until a financial contract expires.","keyPosition":3,"role":null,"values":[{"position":2,"id":"SP","name":"Spot"}]}],"observation":[{"id":"TIME_PERIOD","name":"Time Period","description":"The period of time or point in time to which the measured observation refers.","keyPosition":4,"role":"time","values":[{"start":"2020-07-08T00:00:00","end":"2020-07-08T23:59:59","id":"2020-07-08","name":"2020-07-08"}]}]},"attributes":{"dataset":[],"series":[{"id":"DECIMALS","name":"Decimals","description":"The number of digits to the right of a decimal point.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"4","name":"4"},{"id":"2","name":"2"},{"id":"3","name":"3"},{"id":"6","name":"6"},{"id":"5","name":"5"}]},{"id":"CALCULATED","name":"Calculated","description":"Indicates if the value is calculated or an actual observation.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"false","name":"false"},{"id":"true","name":"true"}]},{"id":"UNIT_MULT","name":"Unit Multiplier","description":"Exponent in base 10 specified so that multiplying the observation numeric values by 10^UNIT_MULT gives a value expressed in the UNIT.","role":null,"values":[{"position":1,"id":"0","name":"Units"},{"position":3,"id":"2","name":"Hundreds"}]},{"id":"COLLECTION","name":"Collection Indicator","description":"Dates or periods during which the observations have been collected.","role":null,"values":[{"position":2,"id":"C","name":"ECB concertation time 14:15 CET"}]}],"observation":[]}}}
```

It seems that the "Id" and "Name" are on the same level. But the actual "Rate" is placed elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still for ease of use you need to create class hierarchy which represents your json structure. You can use some generator and delete all fields you don't actually need. Or you can traverse your json manually. Or create custom converter(which is a nicer version of traversing it manually)

Comment: I don't see a field in this JSON that looks like a 'Rate' value. Are you sure you're using the correct endpoint for what you need?